# Segemented Bar listing dynamic

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter I have been doing segemented bar, for time being I have done the static code and looking to do dynamic I'm facing issue while doing listing to dynamic, Below code is written.

```
     import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:westerAf/paymentPage.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    class EventsPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      EventsPageState createState() => new EventsPageState();
    }

    class EventsPageState extends State<EventsPage> {
      List data = List();

      String url = 'https://d57b9120.ngrok.io/api/events/westernaf/packages';
      Future<String> makeRequest() async {
        var response = await http
            .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

        setState(() {
          var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
          data = extractdata["result"];
        });
      }

      int theirGroupValue = 0;

      final Map<int, Widget> logoWidgets = const <int, Widget>{
        0: Text('Early Bird'),
        1: Text('General'),
        2: Text('Onsite'),
      };

      static Widget giveCenter(String ListView) {
        return Container(
          child: Text(
            "Text: $ListView",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

     @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState(); 
    this.makeRequest();
  }

      List<Widget> bodies = [
        new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(data[i]["package"]),
              subtitle: new Text(data[i]["packageName"].toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ];

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: bodies[theirGroupValue],
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 2.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'title',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 45.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        groupValue: theirGroupValue,
                        onValueChanged: (changeFromGroupValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            theirGroupValue = changeFromGroupValue;
                          });
                        },
                        children: logoWidgets,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

and below code I'm trying to do dynamic. I have the http get request data. here **data** has the list of information and data getting error. I don't know how to do dynamic. please help me to figure out where I went wrong.

```
List<Widget> bodies = [
    new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(data[i]["package"]),
          subtitle: new Text(data[i]["packageName"].toString() +
              ' ' +
              " price: " +
              data[i]["price"].toString()),
        );
      },
    ),
  ];
```

error
[image]

here data is showing in red color, saying that only static member can access init
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the error to your question?

Comment: I have given the error code at last , their data is getting error to me

Comment: May we please know what the error is?

Comment: Instead of ` this.makeRequest();` call `makeRequest();`.

Comment: that I have done above code snippet before, and I have updated the code. But still showing same error , I think near , List<Widget> bodies , we need to define anything which we are struggling or we need to do other ways.

Comment: Try moving the `bodies` definition inside the build function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change

```
@override
  void initState() {
    this.makeRequest();
  }
```

to

```
@override
  void initState() {
   super.initState(); 
    this.makeRequest();
  }
```

Why?

`initState()` is a method called the first time a stateful widget is inserted in the widget-tree.
`super.initState()` forwards to the default implementation of the `State<T>` base class of your widget. You can't miss it in initState method.

2) Change

`List data;`

to

`List data = List();`

Why?

To tell the framework that the list is not fixed. Otherwise it will assume that your list is null, since you have have not assigned any default value to it.

Rest of the code seems fine, it should work. Let us know in comments if it still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for you reply Aman, present Im getting this error: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'data'.                                                                                                                                     data[i]["price"].toString()),

Comment: Have you updated your code with what is mentioned in the answer?

Comment: yes I have update code exactly what you have given to me

Comment: I will upload pic . For our clarity

Comment: I have update to List data = List(); and still it's showing same error, **data** in red color

Comment: Where have you  defined `data` in the class? Could you add that to your question?

Comment: I don't think he has.

Comment: Ty shifting your `bodies` widget before `initState()` is declared

Comment: yup perfect running well. thank you Aman and 10101010 for your help. please do add your answer in proper code I will tick check mark

Comment: You're Welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.